# Nginx server can not start

Tags: nginx, mac-osx-server

My nginx server can't start anymore after I killed its process through `pkill nginx`. Now everytime I try `sudo nginx`, i get this error

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.12.2_1/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

When I navigate to `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.12.2_1/logs`, the directory does not exist. Should I create it manually??
Am in macOs sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating the `logs/error.log` file manually.